# ValueError at /index.............The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: python, html, django

I'm building a socialmedia website in django.While I tried to list all the comments in the index page, i am getting this error, The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

what should i do in this case

views.py....

```
def index(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    allPost = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on').filter(creater = request.user)
    allBlog = Blogpost.objects.all()
    comments = PostComment.objects.filter(post=allPost)
    context = {'allPost' : allPost, 'allBlog' : allBlog, 'comments' : comments}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    
else:
    return render(request, "signoption.html")
```

models.py....

```
class PostComment(models.Model):

    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    comment = models.TextField()

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sno) + '.....comment By.....' + str(self.user)
```

index.html....

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-user">
        <div class="comment-usr-dp">
            <img src="{%static 'img/profile/profile.png'%}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comments-usr-usrname">
        <b><h1>{{comment.user.username}}</h1></b>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-text">
        <h1>{{comment.comment}}</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="comment-time">
        <h1>{{comment.created_on}}</h1>
     </div>
</div>
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `comments = PostComment.objects.filter(post=allPost)` to

> comments = PostComment.objects.filter(post__in=allPost)

Note: **post__in** in filter.

Comment: i have tried doing this......... comments = PostComment.objects.filter(post_in=allPost)............but now it is giving me this error..........Cannot resolve keyword 'post_in' into field. Choices are: comment, created_on, parent, parent_id, post, post_id, postcomment, sno, user, user_id

Comment: You have to add double underscore rather than single as you have used i.e. post__in but not post_in.